# SymPy lambdify raises OverflowError: math range error

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, overflow, sympy

So, I have this code

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import *

u = np.random.uniform(4, 6, 500)
w, k = sp.symbols('w k')
f = sp.log((k - w) * sp.exp((k - w)**5))
l = sum(f.subs(dict(k=k)) for k in u)
```

And now I want to use `l` as a function of `w`. So I know of some options

```
z_lambdify = lambdify(w, l)
z_subs = lambda x: l.subs(w, x)
```

The first function gives an error

```
>>> z_lambdify(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
OverflowError: math range error
>>> z_lambdify(4)
40.862695278600114
```

While the second gives answers

```
>>> z_subs(1)
11469.9130597554
>>> z_subs(4)
40.8626952786003
```

I would just use this, but it is very slow. Any way to get around this (fixing the lamdify error or a way of using `l` as a function that is not so slow)?

Version: Python 2.7.6, NumPy 1.8.1, SymPy 0.7.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answering your question:

The problem is that:

```
z_lambdify = lambdify(w, l)
```

tells the new function to perform the calculations using the built-in `math` functions, which you can check running with `cProfile.run('z_lambdify(1)')`; while doing `z_subs(1)` calls `sympy` functions. To get the same behavior you should tell `lambdify()` to use the same module:

```
 z_lambdify = lambdify(w, l, "sympy")
```

---

### Important suggestion:

You should simplify your function already at its definition and then use`NumPy` to perform the calculations much more efficiently. Using some simple algebra your function can be rewritten in a "non-overflowing" format as:

```
f = lambda k, w: np.log(k - w) + (k - w)**5
```

such that your desired answer can be achieved doing:

```
f(k=u, w=1).sum()
```

when you do `f(k=u, w=1)` you get an array with the same shape of `u`, where each value represents the result of the function evaluated with each value of `u`. You can use this function to simultaneously evaluate `f()` for different values of `k` and `w`, i.e. passing `w` as another array with the same shape of `u` instead of using a constant value.

Comment: Thanks! For the suggestion: I'm not using f but 2nd and 3rd derivatives,  which makes sympy easier. Also, using  numpy.log sometimes gave -inf where sympy.log gave a number.

Comment: @Mauricio all right, just keep in mind the power of NumPy and that some functions can be rearranged in order to avoid overflows (`inf` values for example)... also... remember you can upvote the answers you like...

Comment: Very much forgot about upvotes! And I do prefer NumPy...I will look into how to avoid overflows once I finish up my program. Thanks!